# Add on drop event to a div (No Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a drag/drop excercise, I have a dinamically generated table and a div with a trash bin, so the rows have the "draggable" attribute , but I can't add the "drop" element to my trash bin.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
<div id="tabla" style="margin:30px auto; display:none;">
    <div id="bin" ondrop="drop(event)">
        <img src="icono.png" style="width:100px; margin-left:500px;display:inline;"/><p>
    </div>
    <table id="grid" class="grid">
        <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Password</th>               
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my JS (fragment):

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(localStorage==undefined) {
        alert("Éste navegador no soporta Local Storage");
    } else {
        generarTabla();
        if (localStorage.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('tabla').style.display = 'block';
        var bote = document.getElementById("bin");
        bote.addEventListener("dragleave",handlerLeave,false);
        bote.addEventListener("dragover",handlerOver,false);
        bote.addEventListener("drop",drop,false);
        }
    }
}

function drop(e){
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    }       
    alert("ola");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable dropping on the target element. Add the ondragover attribute to your div like this:

```
<div id="bin" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="icono.png" style="width:100px; margin-left:500px;display:inline;"/><p>
</div>
```

and an allowDrop function such as this:

```
function allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```